# Замена фона с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, замена

Добрый день.
Нужно заменить картинку на одном сайте. Она выводится как бэкграунд для элемента span.
Подключаю такой скрипт:
[window.]document.getElementByClass("ie").style.backroudnImage = "http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
Но фон не меняется. 
Картинку ставлю любую, но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вы не предоставили полного кода, то вот несколько рекомендаций.

1. Код должен быть запущен после того, как DOM будет сформирован. Если проще, то поставьте его после закрывающего тега </body>.
2. Класс .ie должен быть либо единственным, либо быть объявлен первым среди всех других классов .ie .
3. Предоставленный код содержит несколько ошибок, вот исправленная версия:

   document.getElementsByClassName("ie")[0].style.backgroundImage = "http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

или так:

```
document.querySelector(".ie").style.backgroundImage = "http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[window.]document.getElementByClass("ie").style.backroudnImage = "http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
```

если ты этот код копировал с твоего исходника, то проблема в пропущенной 'g' в слове background =)

Comment: Не работает. Даже после исправления.

Comment: `d` и `n` тоже поменяйте местами, если на то уж пошло, а вообще, просто скопируйте слово `backgroundImage`!)

Answer (score 0):

Замените ещё getElementByClass("ie") методом getElementsByClassName("ie").

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так: document.getElementsByClassName("ie")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url([http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png)";](http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png))